# Resetting the value of 'timestamp' in requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, requestanimationframe

I am currently making a slideshow that turns slides after 10 seconds, and using requestAnimationFrame to do so.

I am having some issues with the timestamp, however. I want to keep track of the timestamp value (which is no problem), and when it gets to a value over 10000 (10 seconds), to reset the timestamp to 0 and keep going. However, when I try to change the value of timestamp, nothing happens. Assuming it is a const? Setting a variable to performance.now() with each call is also not behaving quite like I'd expect.

Wondering what the best workaround to this issue would be, maybe some use of performance.now()? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When the loop starts, store a reference to when it starts. Then update that variable, rather than trying to modify the timestamp.

```
let start = null;
let loop = (timestamp) => {
  if (!start) {
    start = timestamp;
  };
  const progress = timestamp - start;
  if (progress > 10000) {
    console.log('loop', start);
    start = timestamp;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
};
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```